# Continuity of a function on the complement of a set of Jordan measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $f:D\subset \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ $f= \begin{cases} c, & \text{if $\vec x \in \Omega$} \\[2ex] 0, & \text{if $\vec x \notin \Omega$} \end{cases}$ where D is a closed rectangle and $\Omega\subset D$ has content zero (i.e its Jordan measure is zero). Prove that $f$ is continuous in $D\setminus \Omega$ (i.e f is continuous in all $\vec x \notin \Omega$)

I have a feeling that this theorem holds: If $\Omega$ is finite: Let $\epsilon>0$ and $\vec x_0 \in D \setminus \Omega$. I can take $\delta= \min \{ \|\vec x - \vec x_0\| : \vec x \in \Omega\}$ so for every $\vec x \in V_{\delta}(\vec x_0)$ , $|f(\vec x)-f(\vec x_0)|=|0-0|<\epsilon$

But I really don´t know how to do the case where $\Omega$ is an infinite set with zero content

I would really appreciate if you can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The statement of the result is equivalent to prove that the set $\Omega$ is closed, but this is not the case in general for a set of content zero (however it's true for finite sets). For example, take $D = [-1,1] \times [-1,1]$ and $\Omega = \lbrace t\cdot (1,1): \; 0 \leq t < \frac{1}{2} \rbrace$. This set has content zero but is not closed, and the function $f$ is not continuous at the point $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}) \notin \Omega$.